# Replacing right derivative with left derivative by replacing $x$ instead of $-x$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I was studying Cartan differential calculus and in section 3, there is a theorem that says:
Assume $f:[a,b] \to F$ and $g:[a,b] \to R$ are continuous and for every $x \in (a,b)$ they have right derivative such that $\Vert f'_d(x)\Vert \leq g'_d(x)$. Then $\Vert f(b)-f(a)\Vert\leq g(a)-g(b)$.

Where $$f'_d(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\ =\lim_{y\to x ,y>0}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$
And for left derivative
$$f'_g(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\ =\lim_{y\to x, y<0}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$
There is a note under this theorem that says: A theorem similar to 3.1.2 is obtained by replacing the derivatives on the right by the derivatives on the left. It can be derived by replacing $x$ by $-x$.

I want to prove the Note part. But I don't know how by replacing $x$ by $-x$, the right derivative becomes left derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ and $g$ satisfy the assumptions but with left derivatives on $(a, b)$ instead of right derivatives on $(a, b)$. Then $\tilde{f}(x) = -f(-x)$ and $\tilde{g}(x) = -g(-x)$ satisfy the assumptions with right derivatives on $(-b, -a)$. Therefore

$$ \lVert f(b) - f(a) \rVert = \lVert \tilde{f}(-a) - \tilde{f}(-b) \lVert
\leq \tilde{g}(-a) - \tilde{g}(-b) = g(b) - g(a).
$$

Comment: Yes, I just pasted the exact note of the book.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: Cartan, differential calculus 1971

Comment: Could you find the book? I think I can send it's pdf for you in chat area.

Comment: @Mina I've now ammended my answer after reading the book